# How to add new CustomXmlDataStoragePropertiesPart if the docx already have some?

Tags: java, xml, docx4j

Actually I added custom xml for docx file which already don't have custom xml and if the docx already have customxml my code just overwrite the existing one(item1 and itemprops1). Say I have docx with customxml. In that custom xml folder there are already eight xmls (item1.xml, item2.xml........item4.xml and itemprops1.xml.........itemprops4.xml). Some how I managed to my elements in new xml (item5.xml) but it doesn't create itemprops5.xml for item5.xml instead it overwrite the itemprops1.xml.

Some of my code are give below for your reference:

```
CustomXmlDataStoragePart custom = new CustomXmlDataStoragePart();

PartName ps = custom.getPartName();
Parts pn = wordMLPackage.getParts();

    CustomXmlDataStoragePart customXmlDataStoragePart = null;

    if (pn.get(ps) == null) {

    customXmlDataStoragePart =injectCustomXmlDataStoragePart(documentPart, wordMLPackage.getParts());
    addProperties(customXmlDataStoragePart);

    } else {

            custom = injectCustomXmlDataStoragePart(documentPart, wordMLPackage.getParts());
            addProperties(custom);

            customXmlDataStoragePart = custom;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the sample [ContentControlsAddCustomXmlDataStoragePart.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ContentControlsAddCustomXmlDataStoragePart.java)

At line 84, it says:

```
parent.addTargetPart(customXmlDataStoragePart, AddPartBehaviour.RENAME_IF_NAME_EXISTS);
```

AddPartBehaviour.RENAME_IF_NAME_EXISTS ensures any existing part is not overwritten, by giving the part a new name.

(Alternatively, you could use the part constructor which takes a PartName argument, to specify the part name you want.)

Please try this sample to confirm it does what you want.  Then you can try adapting the code.